# Use object property inside another property as function

Tags: javascript, object

I'm willing to create an object in js as follows:

```
var item = {
      id:'skate',
      nombre:'electric skate',
      status: StatusByDate(this),    
      enddate: new Date(2022,01,31),
    }
```

and also have this function to work with the *enddate* property:

```
function StatusByDate(obj){
      let hoy = Date.now();
      if(obj.enddate > hoy){
        return "ACTIVE";
      } else {
        return "ENDED";
      }
}
```

However, I'm getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enddate')`, I'm not sure if a property of the object can be used inside a function placed in another property.

Secondly, I'm also interested in good practices, if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is in your example.

Comment: `status: function () { return StatusByDate(this) }`…

Comment: @deceze that is not working either.

Comment: Define "not working"…

Comment: @Germán, if you do it in deceze's way. You need to call the status method like `item.status()` instead of `item.status`. This way it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
function StatusByDate(obj) {
  const hoy = new Date();
  if(obj.enddate > hoy) {
    return "ACTIVE";
  } else {
    return "ENDED";
  }
}

const item = {
  id: 'skate',
  nombre: 'electric skate',
  enddate: new Date(2022, 01, 31),
  get status() { return StatusByDate(this); }
}

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you're trying to reference the object during its creation. However you can create the item, then add its status afterwards as seen in the code below.

```js
var item = {
      id:'skate',
      nombre:'electric skate',   
      enddate: new Date(2022,01,31),
    }

function StatusByDate(obj){
      let hoy = Date.now();
      if(obj.enddate > hoy){
        return "ACTIVE";
      } else {
        return "ENDED";
      }
}

// set the status after the object exists, not during creation
item.status = StatusByDate(item);
console.log(item);
```

Comment: Thank you. When I learned programming (in Java, years ago) the "object" admited to have methods that altered the properties of the object during its creation (not sure if that was inside the constructor) I wonder if there is something similiar in JS.

Comment: @Germán Java and Javascript has zero in common, don't try to think about Javascript in terms of Java. Learn it on its own terms.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to create a class with a constructor so I can apply functions inside of it and get the result right away.

```
class Sorteo{
constructor(id,nombre,status,enddate){
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.estado = setEstadoByDate(enddate);   

function setEstadoByDate(ffin){
        let hoy = Date.now();
        console.log(ffin);
        if(ffin > hoy){
          return "ACTIVO";
        } else {
          return "FINALIZADO";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This could be as simple as `this.estado = enddate > Date.now() ? 'ACTIVO' : 'FINALIZADO'`…